# Spring framework refreshs beans implicitly

Tags: java, spring, singleton

I found out that spring refreshes its singleton beans implicitly and fires a ContextRefreshedEvent.
This behavior is risky for my application.
Is there any way to tell spring not to reset my singleton bean?

Thanks

Comment: There are 5 different scopes of bean 

 1. Singleton
 2. Prototype
 3. Request
 4. Session
 5. Global-Session

I'm sure that Global scope is not reset try to use one of them

Comment: normally singletons will not be refreshed. What is refreshing your ApplicationContext?

Comment: This what I can't find :(
The documentation of spring says it will be refreshed if any context xml file/properties file was changed, I checked the last modified time for all application context files and no one was changed.